# PyQt4: QSpinBox strings

Tags: python, pyqt4, qspinbox

Is there a simple way to create a spinbox in PyQt4 whose varying values are strings? I want to create a spinbox which varies between 'low', 'medium' and 'high'. I've looked around and can't find anything that doesn't look very complicated. In Tkinter it might look trivially like:

```
self.my_wordy_spinbox = Spinbox(parent, 
                                values = ['Medium', 'High', 'Low'],
                                textvariable = self.object_strength)
```

I noticed in the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qspinbox.html) it said "QSpinBox is designed to handle integers and discrete sets of values (e.g., month names)" which I thought might lead to strings but I couldn't find any more on that. I'm tempted to use a combobox instead but I feel that the spinbox would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really see how this would be in any way an improvement over a combo-box, especially if there's more than a few strings.

However, if you really want it, you just need to subclass `QSpinBox` and reimplement [textFromValue](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qspinbox.html#textFromValue) and [valueFromText](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qspinbox.html#valueFromText):

```
class StringBox(QtGui.QSpinBox):
    def __init__(self, strings, parent=None):
        super(StringBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setStrings(strings)

    def strings(self):
        return self._strings

    def setStrings(self, strings):
        self._strings = tuple(strings)
        self._values = dict(zip(strings, range(len(strings))))
        self.setRange(0, len(strings) - 1)

    def textFromValue(self, value):
        return self._strings[value]

    def valueFromText(self, text):
        return self._values[text]
```

Comment: THIS is awesome.  I was able to use it directly in my code.  It was exactly what I was looking for!